# Reading from .dbf with dBASE IV

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, odbc

When trying to read a .dbf file with the *Control Panel -> Region -> Administrative -> Region Settings = "English (UK)"* system settings, Russian characters are read in an unknown encoding. But if this option is switched *Region Settings = "Russian (Russia)"*, then the characters are read correctly. The options I tried are:

1. Modified connection options with a `private constant string SOURCE_CONNECTION_STRING = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Advanced properties = dBASE; Data source = {0};";` to a `private constant string SOURCE_CONNECTION_STRING = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Advanced properties = 'dBASE IV; character set = 1251; HDR = Yes; FMT = delimited"; Data Source = {0}; ";`, but it did not help.
2. Use solution method:

   ```
   private string Decode(string input)
   {
      Encoding fromEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("cp850");
      Encoding toEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);

      string returnValue = toEncoding.GetString(fromEncoding.GetBytes(input));

      return returnValue;
   }
   ```

**Method 2, using explicit decoding, helped me. I would like to know if I can somehow set the encoding I expect explicitly in the settings of the "OleDbConnection" class or in some other way?**

- Here is an example of a received line from a .dbf file - ÇóÔ«¡«¼¡Ù®
  «¬ÓÒú.
- [DBF File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PAzk69CyVpyX-apdSHcMVHpnDR_yYFuD)

Class Example:

```
class DbfReader
{
    private const string COUNT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "count";
    private const string ROW_ELEMENT_NAME = "r";
    private const string MappedTableName = "SOCRBASE";
    private const string SOURCE_CONNECTION_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                                                    "Extended Properties='dBASE IV;characterset=1251;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited'; " +
                                                    "Data Source={0};";

    private static readonly string TableName = "socrbase";
    private static readonly string GetCountQuery = $"select count(1) from [{TableName}]";
    private static readonly List<string> Columns = new List<string> { "level", "scname", "socrname", "kod_t_st" };

    private static string SelectQuery => $"select [level], [scname], [socrname], [kod_t_st] from [{TableName}]";


    public void Convert(string dataSourceFolder)
    {
        using (var srcConn = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(SOURCE_CONNECTION_STRING, dataSourceFolder)))
        {
            srcConn.Open();
            Exception exception = null;

            try
            {
                var xmlFilePath = GetTableFileName(dataSourceFolder, TableName);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(xmlFilePath));
                var xml = new XmlTextWriter(xmlFilePath, Encoding.UTF8);
                xml.WriteStartDocument();
                var reader = new OleDbCommand(SelectQuery, srcConn).ExecuteReader();

                xml.WriteStartElement(MappedTableName);
                xml.WriteAttributeString(COUNT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ((int)new OleDbCommand(GetCountQuery, srcConn).ExecuteScalar()).ToString());
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    xml.WriteStartElement(ROW_ELEMENT_NAME);
                    foreach (var column in Columns)
                    {
                        xml.WriteStartElement(column);
                        var value = reader[column].ToString();
                        var decodeValue = Decode(value);
                        xml.WriteCData(value);
                        xml.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                    xml.WriteEndElement();
                }
                xml.WriteEndElement();
                xml.WriteEndDocument();
                xml.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("XML has been created");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private string Decode(string input)
    {
        Encoding fromEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("cp850");
        Encoding toEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
        string returnValue = toEncoding.GetString(fromEncoding.GetBytes(input));
        return returnValue;
    }

    private string GetTableFileName(string dataSourceFolder, string tableName)
    {
        return Path.Combine(dataSourceFolder, "xml", $"{tableName}.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Modifying the connection properties has nothing to do with displaying the data.  You have to set the encoding in the viewer that you are using to display the results.

Comment: @jdweng, could you give an example? I would really appreciate you

Comment: Encoding only has to do with the way characters are displayed by a viewer.  So it depends on the viewer you are using.  By using method 2 you are simply telling the viewer to use encoding 1251.  There is nothing I can supply as an example other than what you are currently doing.

Comment: @jdweng, thank you. It’s just that I have a problem that depending on the regional settings, my “fromEncoding” changes, and I don’t know how to predict it, I tried to use “Encoding.Default”, but that didn’t help

Comment: You can't predict.  You can either add to the database or add an element to the xml with the encoding/country.

Comment: Yes, I can, but I don't understand how to implement it, because every time the regional settings change, the encoding changes...

Comment: Use "CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;".  There are a number of properties like Name = "en-us" that can be added to the xml to give the information.